# How do I execute ajax success callbacks in an order?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have multiple async AJAX requests happening on my website. What I want to do is put a success callback of each of these requests into a queue and execute them in order. How would I do this?

I looked at plugins like [this](http://gnarf.net/2011/06/21/jquery-ajaxqueue/) or [this](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-message-queuing/docs/files/jquery-ba-jqmq-js.html), but they only seem to put AJAX requests in order, but not their callbacks.

I tried to use [.queue()](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) from jQuery, but I could not get the second queue to execute. Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2zreb/).

```
var q = $({});

$.ajax({
   url: 'test'
})
.done(function () {
    q.queue(function () {
       alert('You should always see this message first.');
    });
});

$.ajax({
    url: 'test'
})
.done(function () {
    q.queue(function () {
        alert('And this next.');
    });
});
```

Comment: The second script you posted seems to put the AJAX requests in order... when each request finishes, its callback is called. Unless you want your second call to wait until the first one finishes, which you'll probably have to handle by yourself

Comment: Do you mean you want to send multiple requests at once, but only allow their callbacks to fire in a given order regardless of what order the requests return in?

Comment: @JamesMontagne That is almost corect, but requests can be sent in parallel and it does not need to be in a batch. Then, once callbacks start firing, I don't want them to fire at once, but in order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `when`:

```
var req1 = $.ajax({
   url: 'test'
})
.done(function () {
    alert('You should always see this message first.');
});

var req2 = $.ajax({
    url: 'test'
});

$.when(req1, req2)
    .done(function () {
        alert('And this next.');
    });
```

or like this:

```
var req1 = $.ajax({
   url: 'test'
})
.done(function () {
    alert('You should always see this message first.');
});

var req2 = $.ajax({
    url: 'test'
})
.done(function () {
    $.when(req1).done(function(){
        alert('And this next.');
    });
});
```

If you have a lot of requests, you could generalize this a bit with an array and a functions.

---

**Untested generic solution**

```
var requests = [];

function queueCallback(deferred, callback){
    requests.push(deferred);
    $.when.apply(null, requests).then(callback);
}
```

then it would be used like this:

```
queueCallback($.ajax(...), function(){ /* callback */});
```

Comment: Thank you, I really like the generic solution you added there. It is working well for me!